# How can I get other users' profiles details in meteor

Tags: meteor, accounts

I have got problem accessing the user profile details of the users other then the current user.

The goal is to display a little footer under a each of the posts in the kind of blog entries list . Footer should consist of the post and author details (like date, username etc.).

Blog entry is identified by authors' _id but the point is that I can not access

```
Meteor.users.find({_id : authorId});
```

Resulting cursor seems to be the same as Meteor.user (not 'users') and consists of one only document, and is valid for the current user ID only. For others, like authors ID, I can only get an empty collection.

The question is, if is there any way, other then next Meteor.users subscription to get authors profile (like username profile.nick etc) ???

Comment: Meteor.users is nothing else than another Collection, so you need to be subscribed to it to fetch data

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to publish all the details of the user based on authorId or something else. By default only the logged in user is published to the client as a matter of security

Comment: It seems so, that's why I ask if there is any tricky solution other then subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** You can [Publish Composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package if you want to get blog entry and user details in a single subscription. See the following sample code and edit as per your collection schemas,

```
Meteor.publishComposite('blogEntries', function (blogEntryIds) {
    return [{
        find: function() {
            return BlogEntries.find({ courseId: { $in: blogEntryIds }});
            // you can also do -> return BlogEntries.find();
            // or -> return BlogEntries.find({ courseId: blogEntryId });
        },
        children: [{
            find: function(blogEntry) {
                return Meteor.users.find({ 
                    id: blogEntry.authorId 
                }, { 
                   fields: { 
                        "profile": 1,
                        "emails": 1
                   } 
                });
            }
        }}
    }]
});
```

**End of update**

You need to publish `Meteor.users` from the server to be able to use it on client. `accounts` package will publish current user, that's why you are only seeing current user's information.

In a file in server folder or in `Meteor.isServer` `if` block do something like this

```
//authorIds = ["authorId1", "authorId2];
Meteor.publish('authors', function (authorIds) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id : { $in: authorIds }});
});
```

or

```
Meteor.publish('author', function (authorId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id : authorId });
});
```

Then on client side subscribe to this publication, in template's onCreated function, with something like this

```
Meteor.subscribe('author', authorId); //or Meteor.subscribe('author', authorIds);
```

or

```
template.subscribe('author', authorId); //or template.subscribe('author', authorIds);
```

Comment: That's working solution but I asked if I there is any other then next subscription way to get the user deatails.

Comment: No. If you remove `autopublish` this is the only way to get user data reactively. If you want one publication for blog entries and users then you might want to use publish-composite package. See my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617821/4-level-subscription-nesting-in-meteor/35619983?noredirect=1#comment58942368_35619983

Comment: What's the server load impact of the Meteor.publishComposite ?

Comment: I've found publish composite to be quite fast in production. Very important though: you need to _limit the fields you return for other users_. For example `{fields: {username: 1}}` otherwise @Kishor's code above will return everything about those users including email addresses, bcrypted password, etc...

Comment: Have got it running. Thank you for your time guys. Have only one bad feeling like going back to relational DB using Mongo :)

Comment: @Kishor Please add a filter for the appropriate fields to your answer. The code above publishes the hashed passwords of the requested users.

Comment: @PaulPaku: publishComposite will be slower compared to normal publish because, the queries in `children` will run once per each record found in the `find` query. For smaller datasets that should be ok. For larger datasets, you can use denormalisation like the other answer mentioned. You might also want to limit the fields like other commenters mentioned above. You should follow good indexing strategies as well to reduce the time. I have updated the answer to restrict the `user`'s collection to only publish `profile` and `emails` in order to stop sending passwords to client side.

Comment: @MichelFloyd: You are right. I should have done that initially, instead, I just focused on the joins. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @DavidWeldon: You are right. I should have done that initially, instead, I just focused on the joins. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only username (or a few other fields), you can save them in post document along with authorId. For example:

```
post:{
   ...
   authorId: someValue,
   authorName: someValue
}
```

You can use them in your templates as a field of a post.
If you have too many fields which you do not want to embed in post document, (so you want to keep only authorId), you can use [publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) when you make your posts publication. (See example 1)

You do not need to publish all your users and their profiles.

Comment: Good idea but will take more storage space. Could be a solution if I forget my "relational" background :)

Comment: Have marked @Kishor's answer as I think it's a popular solution, but my personal feeling is that your idea is more "Mongo way" ready ..

Comment: @PaulPaku this process is known as denormalization you can find more info on when and when not to do it here http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3. At lot of the time its less `expensive` to denormalize do to the fact that you will have to make less round trips to the database to return the data you want. Plus by not doing a server side join you will be using less CPU cycles. These are just few things to keep in mind when using mongo. The article will explain more in detail. Good Luck!

Comment: @PatrickMencias-lewis You are right. As for now, it seems, we will go with denormalized Mongo model without relations.

Comment: @PaulPaku you should also look into meteor before and after hooks. With this you can check if a user has changed their name and if so perform a bulk update on a collection to update the names. Now this is expensive but it rarely happens.